# Combine 2 values in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got 2 columns:

[image]

Year and Quarter.

And in the third column I need to show info from these 2 fields in such way "Q1 23" and so on..

How to make such formula in QY column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
QY = "Q" & 'Table'[Q] &" " &  RIGHT('Table'[Y],2)
```